# What series does Index-tan refer to?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

In the first episode of the Index-tan specials of Toaru Majutsu no Index, Index-tan sits on Touma's head and eats bread. They talk about how she references something and then she explains that if you don't understand the reference, you should buy the Shakugan ** *****-***-DVDs.

[image: Index-tan speaking German]
(It's German)

What does Index-tan refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She is referring to [Shakugan no Shana](http://myanimelist.net/anime/355/Shakugan_no_Shana), a series by the same producer of Index. Here's MAL's blurb on the series:

> He had thought his normal days would last forever, until they were ended abruptly by an encounter with a girl with red hair and eyes. He named her Shana.
>   Not long after he enters high school, Sakai Yuji’s normal days come to an end. He sees something bizarre on his way home: people are frozen in a strange fire, and a monster that looks like a large doll is attacking them. Just when he's about to be killed, a girl in a dark cloak wielding a large sword appears, and slices the monster in half. Although Yuji survives the strange encounter, the girl informs him of a desolate truth: " 'You' don't exist anymore."
>   She calls herself a Flame Haze who hunts "Guze no Tomogara"; intruders from another world. She explains to him that he is a "Torch", a substitute of Yuji whose “existence” has already been devoured. She also told him that he is a special Torch, "Mystes", which contains a precious item in it. When he looks at his chest, he sees within himself a faint flame, just as she said.
>   It is in this way that his eternal struggle alongside the girl begins.

More specifically, she's most likely referring to the [Shakugan no Shana-tan](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1066/Shakugan_no_Shana_Specials) specials, given the number of * in the subs, and the fact that these are the Index-tan specials.

Comment: Well, based on the *s in the subs, it's more likely the Shakugan no Shana-tan specials.

Comment: I had considered the number of * in the subs too, but the specials don't have "tan" in their name. So, most likely, it's really pointing toward [Shakugan no Shana III](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6773/Shakugan_no_Shana_III_%28Final%29). That would fit the number of * there. However, since I was unsure as to which series of the franchise it was referring to, I just put there the name of the franchise itself.

Comment: But they do have -tan in the title... http://blog-imgs-31-origin.fc2.com/s/h/i/shige0819/20070403214019.jpg Since this took place in Index-tan, I think it's quite likely it's referring to the -tan counterpart in the Shana franchise.

Comment: The link you provided is dead.

Comment: http://shakugan.wikia.com/wiki/Shakugan_no_Shana-tan
yeah, it seems to be shakugan no shana-tan on multiple different sites.